# What is the correct way to present and dismiss a modal widget flow?

Tags: flutter, architecture, navigation

I'm quite new to Flutter, coming from iOS development. I'm trying to create a modal widget flow/journey that can be launched from anywhere in the app, and I'm having trouble grasping how to present and dismiss the modal flow correctly.

Whenever I want to present the modal flow from somewhere in the app, this function gets called:

```
Widget launchModalFlow() {
  return Navigator(
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (BuildContext _) => FirstStepScreen(
        didComplete: (context) {
          _pushSecondScreen(context); // this is a method which uses Navigator.of(context) to push another widget onto the navigation stack
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

It is called like this:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return launchModalFlow();
  },
  fullscreenDialog: true,
));
```

Whenever I want to dismiss the modal flow, I do this from within the modal flow, for example when you tap Close in the app bar or reach the end of the flow:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

While this *sort of works*, it doesn't feel right for (probably more, but mainly) two reasons:

1. The modal flow shouldn't need to care about from where it was presented. Now it assumes that it was presented on the root navigator, which works for now but may break in the future.
2. The first screen in the modal flow doesn't automatically get a Close button in the scaffold app bar. I'm under the impression that if things are done correctly, you will get it for free. Is this correct?

So I guess my question is: if I present the modal flow using a navigator that isn't the root navigator, how can I get a reference to the presenting navigator to dismiss the flow? Or am I taking an entirely incorrect approach doing it like this?

Foot notes:

1. Code examples are cut for brevity
2. I'm using iOS terminology (present and dismiss), sorry about that!
3. I've only ever tested this on an iOS simulator so far